How to combine multiple rows with same ID into just one row while maintaining other column data?
I am using the latest RStudio version (as of 9/30/2024). I have a dataset with >30,000 observations that contains all the medications that my patients have taken. The dataset is in a form in which each medication has its own row even if the same patient is taking multiple medications. Please see the example data table below.
My request is: how do I combined all the rows with the same ID into just one row and make the medication names as columns? My overall goal is to be able to code for broad classes of medications (e.g., anti-cholesterol meds, antiepileptic meds, antihypertensives, etc.) where I have a column for each broad class of med (e.g., anti-cholesterol) and any patient taking any anticholesterol med would have a "1". I can do this last part but I need assistance with combining all the rows with same ID into just one row and making medication names as columns.
Here is example data: please note that not every patient is taking a medication.
ID  AnyDrug DrugName
10001   2   
10002   2   
10003   2   
10004   2   
10005   1   Atorvastatin
10006   2   
10007   1   Hydrochlorothiazide
10008   1   Lisinopril
10008   1   Atorvastatin
10008   1   Metoprolol
10008   1   Latanaprost
10009   1   Acetazolomide
10009   1   Enalapril
10010   1   Atorvastatin
10010   1   Lisinopril

Ideally, I am looking to transform my data so that it can look something like the following table:
ID  AnyDrug Atorvastatin    Hydrochlorothiazide Lisinopril  Metoprolol  Latanaprost Acetazolomide   Enalapril   Carvedilol  Amlodipine
10001   2                                   
10002   2                                   
10003   2                                   
10004   2                                   
10005   1   1                               
10006   2                                   
10007   1       1                           
10008   1   1       1   1   1               
10009   1                       1   1       
10010   1   1       1

I would be most grateful for your help. Thank you!

See linked post, something like this should work: dcast(d, ID + AnyDrug ~ DrugName, fun.aggregate = length)

You may want to join a table which says which drugs are which broad class.  Then do the pivot/dcast.
